# Determining if a directed graph is unilateral

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, adjacency-list

How would you go about finding out if a directed graph is unilateral (for any pair of verticles `u`,`v`, at least one is reachable from the other)?
I'm thinking that you could run DFS or BFS and see if you can reach every vertex.  If not, compute the transpose and do the same search algorithm from the same vertex.  If you have reached every vertex at least one, is the graph unilateral?

Obviously you could do this in large running times by just analyzing an adjacency matrix, but ideally we want to run in O(V+E)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure whether this is correct, but I think that it should suffice to check if the digraph is "connected" (see description of the algorithm below to find out what I mean by connected). If there are multiple connected components in the digraph, then it is not unilateral.

**Proof attempt:**

Suppose that the digraph has multiple connected components. For simplicity's sake, let the number of connected components be 2, and let's call the components `C1` and `C2`. Select any vertex `v` from `C1` and any vertex `w` from `C2`. Since they are in different connected components, there is no path from `v` to `w` or `w` to `v`, otherwise `C1` and `C2` will be in the same component.

For the other case, suppose that a digraph is connected. Then for any 2 distinct vertices `x` and `y` in the digraph, there is either a path from `x` to `y` or from `y` to `x`, otherwise they will not be in the same component. I know it's a bit hand wavy here, but I'm not exactly good at proofs.

**EDIT: A simpler algorithm:**

I do think a modified **Depth First Search** / **Breadth First Search** should be able to do it. Essentially, we can start the search from **any** vertex. We mark all vertices reachable from that first vertex as visited. Then loop through all vertices. For any unvisited vertex, we conduct a BFS / DFS, and we use a list to keep track of all unvisited vertices that we have traversed. If during the BFS / DFS, we do not visit any previously visited vertex from a prior BFS / DFS, then we can conclude immediately that the digraph has multiple connected components and is not unilateral. Otherwise, we mark all vertices in the list we obtained during the search as visited, and we continue.

Once we have gone through all vertices in the graph all the BFS / DFS hit some previously visited vertex, we can conclude that the graph is unilateral.

Some pseudocode to illustrate this. I shall make use of Depth First Search:

```
// a boolean array to keep track if a given vertex is visited
// initially this is set to false
boolean[] visited
// boolean array to keep track of visited vertices for 2nd dfs onwards
boolean[] visited_two

// used for first dfs
dfs(vertex) {
  visited[vertex] <- true
  for each edge leading out of vertex {
    dfs(next vertex)
  }
}

// used for subsequent dfs
dfs_two(vertex, list_for_storing_vertices) {
  // we use the visited_two array here, because the
  // visited array is used to store previously visited
  // vertices
  visited_two[vertex] <- true
  list_for_storing_vertices.append(vertex)
  // return value. we return true if we encounter
  // a previously visited vertex. otherwise, return false
  return_value <- false
  for each edge leading out of vertex {
    if visited[next vertex]
      return_value <- true
    else if !visited_two[next_vertex]
      r = dfs_two(next vertex, list_for_storing_vertices)
      return_value = return_value || r
  }
  return return_value
}

// overall algorithm
// Returns true if the graph is unilateral. false otherwise
bool digraph_unilateral(graph) {
  // Just pick any vertex. we will pick vertex 0
  set all entries in `visited` array to false
  dfs(0)
  // then loop through all vertices. if they haven't been visited,
  // we perform a dfs
  for each vertex in the digraph {
    if !visited[vertex] {
      // reset visited_two array
      set all entries in `visited_two` array to false
      visited_list <- []
      encountered_previously_visited <- dfs_two(vertex, visited_list)
      if encountered_previously_visited {
        // mark the vertices we encountered as visited
        for each v in visited_list {
          visited[v] <- true
        }
      } else {
        // we did not encounter any previously visited vertex
        // so all vertices we encounter on this search are in
        // a distinct connected component
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

**Original, more difficult algorithm:**

How do we then compute if a digraph is unilateral? You can first run [**Tarjan's Strongly Connected Components algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) and determine the strongly connected components of the digraph. You will need to modify the algorithm slightly to compress the strongly connected components into supervertices. This is not difficult to do, just assign each vertex in the same strongly connected component an integer label. In other words, all the vertices in the same strongly connected component will be replaced by 1 supervertex. Tarjan's SCC (Strongly Connected Components) algorithm runs in `O(V+E)` time.

After the step above, the digraph is now **acyclic** (no cycles). This allows us to move on to the next step.

After that, perform a **topological sort** on the resulting graph from above. This should give us a **topological ordering** of the directed acyclic graph. This step also runs in `O(V+E)` time using a depth first search implementation.

Now that we have the topological ordering, perform either **Breadth First Search** or **Depth First Search** according to the **topological ordering** on the **directed acyclic graph** obtained after the Tarjan's SCC step. If the number of connected components is 1, then the original graph is unilateral (it is also unilateral if the number of connected components is 0, but that is an empty graph and so is trivial). Otherwise, there are multiple components, and the original graph is not unilateral. This step also runs in `O(V+E)` time.

Therefore, the overall algorithm runs in `O(V+E)` time.

**Conclusion**

I think this should be correct, but you might want to verify this approach with someone else. If you have any difficulty in understanding my approach or implementing the algorithms, do leave a comment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't seen Tarjan's, but I do like the idea of strongly connected components!  Why would getting the strongly connected components get rid of cycles though?  Is it not possible to have a cycle between three components?            Also, then when you do the final search on the strongly connected components, you're hoping that every vertex is reachable?

Comment: Sorry I was caught up with something. A strongly connected component (abbrev as **SCC** from now on) `C` of a digraph is a subgraph where any vertex `v` in `C` can reach any vertex `w` in `C`. At least 1 **directed cycle** can be found in an SCC. By replacing SCCs with supervertices, there will be no SCCs remaining in the digraph. Otherwise there should have been a larger SCC found instead of the original. To use your example, if there's a cycle between three components, they will be regarded as a single SCC by Tarjan's SCC algo instead of 3 separate SCCs

Comment: No problem =) I would recommend getting a copy of [this](https://sites.google.com/site/stevenhalim/) book if you are interested in coding out the algorithm. It has **working** C++ code for tarjan's scc, topological sort, bfs, dfs. There is also a free copy of the first edition here: http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/myteaching/competitive_programming/cp1.pdf

Comment: I don't believe your simpler algorithm works. Take the 3 vertex graph [(v1,v0), (v2,v0)] (I.e. 2 edges from vertex v1 and v2 to vertex v0). This graph isn't unilateral (there is no path from v1 to v2, or v2 to v1), but your algorithm will give a false positive: First DFS will just visit v0. Second DFS from v1 will visit v0 and since v0 has already been visited assume everything is fine. Then third DFS from v2 will visit v0 and also assume everything is fine. Now all vertices have been visited and the algorithm reports true. Or am I misunderstanding the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Try [these algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability). The one I learned in college was Floyd-Warshall, but its performance is not as good as you desire. [Johnsons's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) is faster for sparse graphs, but still O(V*E), not O(V+E).

Answer (score 0):

Find the strongly connected components with, say, [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).  Every node in an SCC is reachable from any other, so they are equivalent in terms of which nodes they can reach and be reached by.  Collapse each SCC into a single vertex, and the resulting DAG will be unilateral iff the original graph was unilateral.

A DAG is unilateral iff if it is a total ordering, i.e, if there is only one topological order.  If there is a path from A to B, then A must come before B.  If there is a path from B to A, then B must come before A.  You can't have both, because the graph is now acyclic.  If there is no path between A and B, then then they are not ordered and there are at least 2 topological orders for the graph -- one with A before B, and one with B before A.

A fast way to check for a total order is to do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn%27s_algorithm) with Kahn's algorithm, and check to ensure that there is only one choice for the next vertex at every iteration.

Tarjan's algorithm for finding SCCs, Collapsing the SCCs, and Kahn's algorithm for topological sort, all run in O(V+E) time.